# How to transfer data between two tables using react jsx?

Tags: reactjs

I have two tables, one named active and one named inactive, with a tab to switch between the two. I am using a modal that has a button inside it called "deactivate" to deactivate a item, how do I move all of the data from the active tab to the inactive tab via the modal?

Comment: Try this `const a = b`